# How to use Windows Identity Framework (WIF) without Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-identity

We want to use Windows Identity Framework 2.0 which was just released a few days ago.

It has a dependency on Entity Framework.  However the database we use doesn't have an Entity Framework driver.

How can we use it without Entity Framework and do straight ADO .NET persistence instead of using the Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.  I found what I needed here:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

Answer (score 1):

Windows Identity Foundation(WIF) was a separate library that could be used to do claims based identity. It was first released as 3.5 and could be used with .NET 3.5. In .NET 4.5 it was built in to .NET. What was recently released is ASP.NET Identity and is really unrelated to Windows Identity Foundation, except that ASP.NET Identity can store claims for a user in its database. But it's not the same thing as WIF.

Comment: Thanks brock, I figured that out. We got our implementation up and running with a custom storage provider on IBM i DB2 database. It took a lot of work, and had to implement some custom caching due to the fact we didn't use an ORM and the Identity framework does a ton of Updates to the main identity model object.  Sort of wish we did it using NHibernate at this point (no entity framework driver for IBM i DB2 without lots of $$$)